# Trying to reference a hash using a string value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, variables, hash, string-interpolation

How would I refer to a hash using the value of a string - i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
foo = Hash.new
bar = "foo"
"#{bar}"["key"] = "value"
```

results in

```
 foo:5:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)
 from foo:5
```

How do I use the value of bar (foo) to reference the hash named foo? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
foo = Hash.new
bar = "foo"
instance_eval(bar)["key"]="value"
```

At this context `eval(bar)` also works

instance_eval tries to execute(as ruby code) the string that you give at first argument in the current context.

In your example, Ruby is trying to invoke the String#[]= method. And you don't want that :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 That's nice and saves some messing around escaping strings

Comment: Agreed - this is a very clean solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can eval the string as follows :-

```
foo = Hash.new
bar = "foo"
eval "#{bar}[\"key\"]=\"value\""
puts foo   # {"key"=>"value"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, **eval is evil**, but it works:

```
>> foo = Hash.new
{}
>> bar = "foo"
=> "foo"
>> eval(bar)["key"] = "value"
=> "value"
>> foo
=> {"key"=>"value"}
```